# Can I hide html page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

let's say i have a website example.com and a page example.com/DHAS5KJ1H45GAS.html. There is no links to said page anywhere except mysql database.

I'm assuming there is a setting to make search engines ignore the page (noindex, nofollow).

So my question: is there a program that can find all website's pages?

PS: I'm trying to make a page accessible only for users that know the passcode (without registration), i have mysql database with code/link pairs.

Maybe there is a better way to do this?

Comment: it's too broad to answer.

Comment: Idea: maybe i can use <?php  if ... > to check if the person has entered the correct code on the main page. I would have to use cookies then?

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: so just add a "passcode" check to the page. obfuscation is not secure

Comment: you could save the html code in the database and generate the page on the fly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give a file a random name and don't have it linked anywhere publicly (and don't have indexing enabled in your web server), there is theoretically no way that it would be found by anyone without the link.

Do keep in mind, however, that anything you put in the URL will get stored to the user's browser history (someone who REALLY wanted to invade your website might use bruteforce [CSS history knocking](http://samy.pl/csshack/) to exploit this if your codes weren't sufficiently random), and that it'd be pretty easy for anyone who had access to share the URL.

Comment: The first sentence is false. If there's no link and someone has to go to it directly, it will still get logged in ISP logs when they go to it so someone working at the ISP snooping through the logs will know the page exists.

Comment: thanks! In conclusion I used server to store all content and get it only when a correct passcode is entered. No hidden pages and passcode can change after every request. This seems to work fine

Answer (score 0):

Create a robots.txt file in the root of your web directory, and set the content to:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

This will prevent the site from being indexed by search engines. You can make the settings as specific as you'd like to allow/disallow pages more specifically, if need be.

Comment: it will work on the bots that take notice of the *suggestion* but will have no effect on those that ignore it. its a "do not enter" sign on an unlocked door

Comment: Right, it won't stop a bot that ignores it. If the pages aren't linked to, however, the bots aren't going to find it in the first place. They'd have to guess

Comment: just like password cracking then.

Comment: More or less. The only way it's going to get indexed is if someone submits a link somewhere or a crawler is trying to brute force the site. If that's the case, the clear answer here is, "no, you can't hide your site." But you can at least set your robots.txt to prevent indexing to take a proactive step to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

If this file has constant name you can apply mod_rewrite. Simply create the file *.htaccess* in the folder where the file is located and put following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/?DHAS5KJ1H45GAS\.html$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```